# Pandas Count values across rows that are greater than another value in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count, rows

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
        X   a   b   c
        1   1   0   2
        5   4   7   3
        6   7   8   9
```

I want to print a column called 'count' which outputs the number of values greater than the value in the first column('x' in my case). The output should look like:

```
X   a   b   c   Count
1   1   0   2   2
5   4   7   3   1
6   7   8   9   3
```

I would like to refrain from using '**lambda function**' or '**for**' loop or any kind of looping techniques since my dataframe has a large number of rows. I tried something like this but i couldn't get what i wanted.

```
df['count']=df [ df.iloc [:,1:] > df.iloc [:,0] ].count(axis=1)
```

I Also tried

```
numpy.where()
```

Didn't have any luck with that either. So any help will be appreciated. I also have nan as part of my dataframe. so i would like to ignore that when i count the values.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using `ge`(>=) with `sum`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].ge(df.iloc[:,0],axis = 0).sum(axis = 1)
Out[784]: 
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

After assign it back

```
df['Count']=df.iloc[:,1:].ge(df.iloc [:,0],axis=0).sum(axis=1)
df
Out[786]: 
   X  a  b  c  Count
0  1  1  0  2      2
1  5  4  7  3      1
2  6  7  8  9      3
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks a lot @Wen. That was quick. I have a follow up question. In my case i actually have 2 columns 'x' and 'y' and i need to count the value that lies between the two ranges. so can i combine '.le' and '.ge' and have an '&' operator? How does that work? I know i should've included this in my first question.

Comment: got it. In case anyone needs such a solution,

Comment: @sandy yes you can using &

Answer (score 1):

```
df['count']=(df.iloc[:,2:5].le(df.iloc[:,0],axis=0).sum(axis=1) + df.iloc[:,2:5].ge(df.iloc[:,1],axis=0).sum(axis=1))
```

In case anyone needs such a solution, you can just add the output you get from '.le' and '.ge' in one line. Thanks to @Wen for the answer to my question though!!!

Comment: Also @Wen , may i know why you used axis=0 for 'le' function. I understand axis=1 because the calculation needs to be done column to column. But why axis=0?

Comment: This is match by row index. axis=1 they will search the column index match and calculated the value when it is matched